# how do icon maps (or chart) work?

Tags: html, css, icons

i always found something similar while i look inside some websites source code
all the icons are gathered in one chart .. i realized later that they refer to each icon separately when its needed. i found a good article about image mapping in w3schools
it gift me the main idea but i still need how it works
can i have more information about how this is done ? articles or anything to learn more
thank to everyone

[image]

Answer (score 2):

They're called 'CSS sprites', Chris Coyier wrote a pretty authoritative article on the subject http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/